# How to reference ReactJs in Html file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, reactjs

I am new in ReactJs , I am trying to use it with Microsoft visual studio 2017 . 
I installed ReactJs from Nuget Package , and it was successfully installed and now i have a scripts folder that contains the files as you can see in the screenshot .

I created a new Html file and i am trying to write code to create react component inside the page , i referenced react.Js file ,, but the intellsence did not appear and the component was not displayed in the run time .

i don't know how to reference the reactJs to make my code working , I searched internet but i found all is talking about JSXTransformer , but i think this was about old versions of ReactJs.

I am using version 0.14.7[image: React component inside Html file]

Comment: I'm surprised the console didn't throw any errors, but it's `renderComponent` and not `renderComponant`. The difference is a spelling mistake. However, and still yet, `renderComponent` is deprecated in newer versions of react. You should instead be using the `react-dom` library and using `ReactDOM.render(<Component/>, container);`

Answer (score 0):

A few issues here.

1. You need to include react.js and react-dom.js to use react. So add another script that points to react-dom.js. Alternatively you could also use their minified versions that is available in your Scripts/react directory. You can also use a CDN like I have done below.
2. To render your react component into the DOM, you need to use `ReactDOM.render` instead.
3. You also have to add babel.js in your script. Without babel.js, the browser will not be able to recognise the JSX in your Hello component. Note that I am using version 5.8.24, it will not work in version 6 and above. Lastly, change the script type from `text/jsx` to `text/babel`.

See working example below.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
  var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function (){
      return (<div>Hello at {this.props.now}</div>);
    } 
  });
  
  ReactDOM.render(<Hello now={new Date().toString()}/>, document.getElementById('container'));

</script>
```